# Adding new object to table in database using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

i am building an online shopping store using asp.net core 6 mvc. there are three models in the application. Product, order, orderLine.

The user have to choose first a category from landing page, so it is displayed home page of products of that category, then the user select an item and then moves to details view where user can add the selected item to the cart. the problem is when i am trying to add new OrderLine to the database no change is happened in database and no errors pop up.

**Details view**

```
@model Product

<form method="post" asp-action="Details">
<main class="row-cols-2">
    <div class="left-column">
       
        <img data-image="red" asp-for="Image" class="active" src="@Model.Image" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="right-column">

        <div class="product-description">
            
            <h1 asp-for="Title">@Model.Title</h1>
            <p sp-for="Details">@Model.Details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price">
            <span sp-for="Price">@Model.Price KR</span>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for=" @Model.Id"></input>
            <button type="submit" class="cart-btn">Add to cart</button>
        </div>

</main>

</form>
```

**Detalis action**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Product product)
    {
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var orderLine = new OrderLine(4);
        orderLine.Product = product;

        _db.Add(orderLine);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = product.Categ });
    }
```

**OrderLine model**

```
  public class OrderLine
{

    public OrderLine() { }

    public OrderLine( int amount)
    {
       
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Amount { get; set; } = 1;

    public Order? Order { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product? Product { get; set; }


}
```

**Product model**

```
 public class Product
{
    public Product() { }

    public Product(string title, Category.Categ categ, string details, decimal price, string image)
    {
       
        Title = title;
        Categ = categ;
        Details = details;
        Price = price;
        Image = image;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public Category.Categ Categ { get; set; } = Category.Categ.babies;
    public string Details { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<OrderLine> OrderLine { get; set; } = new List<OrderLine>();




}
```

here is the response on the browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbBLz.png)

Comment: You described the problem, but you forgot to show us what you actually did. The code is critical for us being able to help you, as we have no idea what you did wrong without it. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: i have posted the code now

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? Does it flow through the code as you expect it to? What result does this action method end up returning?

Comment: could you show your product instance passed into the controller? Which table has no change（ all table？）

Comment: the product instance is passed into controller but OrderLines table does not changed.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the problem. the problem was that there is a relation between OrderLine MODEL AND Order model so that it is impossible to create new instance of orderLine without assigning OrderId to it. the solution is to make OrderId in  OrderLine model nullable.